# Scroll to div smoothy on page 2 - after clicking on a link on page 1?

Tags: jquery

I have a link to (news)article from a ie cover page (page 1) looking something like this..

```
<a href="nn.com/stories/being_at_mall.html#article">Read this story</a>
```

On the other, destination page (page 2), div awaits with this remark

```
<div id="#article"></div>
```

What I wish to do/try is;

- after clicking on a link on page 1, first for page 2 to loads up and stay at a very top for maybe 1 second (for user to enjoy header on page 2 a bit lol),
- and after that intro, for page to smoothly scroll down itself to anchored div.

I have a marked very top of a page like (<`div id="top"></div>`) if needed.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Check out [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code when being_at_mall.html file loads

```
$(function () {
    $(document.body).animate({
        scrollTop: $(location.hash).offset().top
    }, {
        duration: 'slow',
        easing: 'swing'
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfsdu/2/) You can see in the demo that it scrolls when the page loads. The above code uses `location.hash` which will give you `#article` i.e. the id to the element in being_at_mall.html.

Also [this page](http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-scroll-elements-smoothly-in-javascript-jquery-without-plugins/)* lists more options on how to scroll smoothly along with demo.

* I'm the author of that page. I created that when I was learning jQuery.

Comment: Thx for effort Lobo! I made some code very close to yours with some intervals also to fit these needs.

Answer (score 0):

Embed this code in your js file. this will run on "**hashchange**" event.
When in URL it found like **pageName#sectionID** the page will scroll to that section.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var ids;
function offsetAnchor() {

if(location.hash.length !== 0) {
    ids = location.hash;
    var scrollAmnt =  $(ids).offset().top;
    setTimeout(function() {$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:scrollAmnt},2000);}, 500);}
}

$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    offsetAnchor();
});

window.setTimeout(function() {
    offsetAnchor();
    event.preventDefault();
}, 1);

setTimeout(function() {$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:00},0000);}, 10);  
});
```